# How to implement a progress bar in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, progress-bar, mongrel

We want to implement a progress bar for file uploading in one of our Ruby application. This needs to show the exact percentage of the upload. However, despite our best efforts we could not find a way to implement a progress bar that exactly replicate the file upload process.

Can you please help us with this?

Answer (score 1):

If your are using Apache and Passenger, you can use the Apache progress bar module.

Screencast:
http://www.railsillustrated.com/screencast-file-uploads-progress-in-rails-passenger.html

Apache Module and installation instructions:
http://drogomir.com/blog/2008/6/18/upload-progress-bar-with-mod_passenger-and-apache

Comment: People don't use Mongrel in Production anyway, you would probably end up using Nginx and Mongrel Clusters. In any case, I think there are plugins for Mongrel as well As Nginx. I haven't tried it using Mongrel but as always "Google is your friend" or try at the irc #rubyonrails

Comment: Sure people use Mongrel in production, if Apache or Nginx are overkill. It's about the right tool for the job and for low traffic sites, especially inside a firewall, Mongrel is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [mongrel_upload_progress](http://techno-weenie.net/2006/9/4/mongrel-upload-progress-documentation) in the past, but I found that it was quite a complex and delicate solution to the problem. I'd definitly recommend looking towards using passenger thru apache for your production environment, though.